# timer couldn't work with wiringPiISR (QtQuick application)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer, wiringpi

I have created a class `Capteur_Input` and one of the options in the constructor creates an interrupt using `wiringPiISR`

`wiringPiISR(m_pin, INT_EDGE_RISING, isrInput);`

my class also has an attribute `m_impulsion` and I am incrementing this value each time that an interruption happens.

this what my interrupt handler looks like

```
void Capteur_Input::isrCallback()
{
    if(m_pin== Pin_vitesse)
{
    increment_impulsion();
        emit digital_inputChanged(m_impulsion);
}
    else
        emit digital_inputChanged(m_value);
}
```

in my `main.cpp` I created an instance of this class

```
static void isrInput_vitesse();

static Capteur_Input vitesse(Pin_vitesse,PUD_OFF,INT_EDGE_RISING,isrInput_vitesse);

static void isrInput_vitesse()
{
    vitesse.isrCallback();
}
```

every thing is working fine, the qml and C++ part.

and now I want to calculate the number of impulse detected per second. but I couldn't do it.

my class `Capteur_Input` also has a timer, I configured it in the constructor

```
m_timer =new QTimer (this);
    m_timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    connect (m_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(onTimeout()));
    m_timer->start(500);
```

and I tried to test in the SLOT onTimeout() someting but this `qDebug()<<"VITESSEEEEEEEE"<<m_pin <<readPin()<<vitesse;` never shows up. I don't know why maybe because wiringPiISR is a thread and has a higher priority than the timer?
can someone explain to me please, how to make a timer that calculates the exact time and make the interrupt work in the same time?
the timer is working for the other instances of this class that are just inputs no interruptions

```
void Capteur_Input::onTimeout()
{
    qDebug()<<"time is up"<<m_pin;

    if(m_pin== Pin_vitesse)
    {
        qDebug()<<"m_pin== Pin_vitesse";
    int vitesse;

    vitesse= int (calcul_vitesse/4*2.166);//*0.001/3600;
    qDebug()<<"VITESSEEEEEEEE"<<m_pin <<readPin()<<vitesse;

    emit vitesse_Changed(vitesse);
    qDebug()<<"VITESSEEEEEEEE"<<m_pin <<readPin()<<vitesse;


    }
    else{

        emit digital_inputChanged(readPin());
        qDebug()<<"signal DIGITAL emitted m_pin"<<m_pin <<"value"<<readPin();
    }
}
```

actually the slot onTimeout is working for these 2 instances

```
#define Pin_vitesse 3
#define PinFrein 0
#define PinClignotnat_G 2

Capteur_Input frein(PinFrein,PUD_UP,NO_INTERRUPT);
Capteur_Input clignotant_G(PinClignotnat_G,PUD_DOWN,NO_INTERRUPT);
```

and is not working for this one which is an interrupt `static Capteur_Input vitesse(Pin_vitesse,PUD_OFF,INT_EDGE_RISING,isrInput_vitesse);`

and this what I got as an output

```
time is up 0
signal DIGITAL emitted 0 1
time is up 2
signal DIGITAL emitted 2 0

time is up 0
signal DIGITAL emitted 0 1
```

the timer is working for the other instances and it is not working for the one that is an interrupt

Comment: It could be you have a loop on `emit vitesse_Changed(vitesse)` because the slot that the signal is connected to will run if it's a `DirectConnection`. Hence if you moved the qDebug call to the line before you may see it appear

Comment: I moved it but it didn't appear :/

Comment: It seems that the event loops that handle timer events didn't work (main event loop). Do you have something like app.exec() ? Capteur_Input is QObject based with Q_OBJECT macro in the class definition?

Comment: I edited my post ,  the timer works fine for the other instances of this class and the class Capteur_Input inherites fron Capteur_ which is a QObject class and contains the macro Q_OBJECT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static QObject instance is not supported in Qt, as stated below (QObject reentrancy [section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) ):

> In general, creating QObjects before the QApplication is not supported
> and can lead to weird crashes on exit, depending on the platform. This
> means static instances of QObject are also not supported. A properly
> structured single or multi-threaded application should make the
> QApplication be the first created, and last destroyed QObject.

If you need a callback when isr interrupt comes up, a static pointer should work:

```
static void isrInput_vitesse();

static Capteur_Input *vitesse = nullptr;

static void isrInput_vitesse()
{
    if(!vitesse) //not initialized yet
         return; 
    
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod( vitesse, "isrCallback", Qt::QueuedConnection ); //or blockingQueue if you need to handle it directly in Qt way.
}
```

The `vitesse` pointer should be initialized in main() after the initialization of QApplication instance.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
       QApplication a(argc, argv);

       //.....  your main application body  

       vitesse = new  Capteur_Input(Pin_vitesse,PUD_OFF,INT_EDGE_RISING,isrInput_vitesse);

       //...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. but I got an error when I tried to test this telling that `invokeMethod  is not a membre of QObject` and also  `QVariant::QVariant(void*)` is private within this context
    ctx->setContextProperty("vitesse", &vitesse); 
                                                ^

Comment: My mistake, it means QMetaObject instead of QObject. I've edited my answerer. `isrCallback` should be declared as a Qt slot function.

Comment: it fixed the first error and as you said I declared isrCallback as a slot `public slots:
    void isrCallback(); `but I still got these two errors :83: error: ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’ is private within this context
     ctx->setContextProperty("vitesse", &vitesse);
                                                ^

Comment: 83: error: use of deleted function ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’
     ctx->setContextProperty("vitesse", &vitesse);
                                                ^

Comment: in the error when I click on the `declare private here` and `declare here` it leads me tho the `qvariant.h` and to this line 
`\private:
    // force compile error, prevent QVariant(bool) to be called
    inline QVariant(void *) = delete;
    // QVariant::Type is marked as \obsolete, but we don't want to
    // provide a constructor from its intended replacement,
    // QMetaType::Type, instead, because the idea behind these
    // constructors is flawed in the first place. But we also don't`

Comment: As I don't have your codes, the setContextProperty() seems to use `vitesse` instance pointer  as its "vitesse" properties. Try to modify it to `ctx->setContextProperty("vitesse", vitesse)` because vitesse variable is now a pointer, not a class instance.

Comment: oh yes it is a pointer .. now it is working :D  thank you A LO. it s been a while that I am trying to fix this ! THANK YOU again :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeout` signal might be interfered or delayed.

You may try to specify a [Qt::Connectiontype](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.ConnectionType.html) to force Qt to treat your `timeout` signal as soon as it is emitted.

```cpp
QObject::connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Capteur_Input::onTimeOut, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

This will deliver the `timeout` signal to the `ontimeOut` slot as soon as it is emitted.

Comment: I just edited my post , the timer is working correctly with the 2 others instances of this class that are not a interrupt.